Model validations for specific scenario, Rails
I've using a calendar gem that uses start_time for the date (YYYY-MM-DD).
For example purposes I've got Meeting, which has start_time string and postponed boolean attributes.
@meeting.start_time must be at least one day in the future (the day after today), but you can't set a new start_time (Meeting Date) if @meeting.postponed, only if @meeting.postponed == false
Also, if @meeting.postponed, cannot un postpone it without setting a new @meeting.start_time (that is at least one day in the future).
I would like validations so when updating the Meeting (if @meeting was previously postponed), I want to unselect the @meeting.postponed checkbox and submit a new @meeting.start_date in the form, and have it pass in the same submission.
if in the controller, something like:
@meeting.attributes = meeting_params

if @meeting.start_time != "" && @meeting.start_time != nil
  if @meeting.start_time_changed?
    if @meeting.posteponed
      @error = "Can't change the Meeting Date if the Meeting is still postponed."
    else
      if @meeting.start_time.to_date <= Date.today
        @error = "Meeting must be at least one day in the future."
      end
    end
  else
    if @meeting.postponed_changed? && @meeting.postponed == false
      @error = "You can't un postpone the Meeting without setting a new Meeting Date."
    end
  end
else
  @error = "Meeting Date cannot be blank."
end

How can I do this with validations?
UPDATE:
As per max, this works for my specific scenario:
validates :start_time, presence: true
  validate :start_time_must_be_in_future, 
    if: :start_time? # prevents a nil error
    #unless: :postponed?,

  validate :start_time_cannot_change,
    if: :postponed?,
    on: :update    
  validate :postponed_cannot_become_false_unless_a_new_start_time_is_submitted_that_is_not_in_the_past,
    if: !:postponed? && :postponed_changed?,
    on: :update

private

  def start_time?
    !start_time.nil? && start_time != ""
  end

  def start_time_must_be_in_future
    errors.add(
      :start_time,
      "-- The date of the meeting cannot be in the past (must be either today or in the future)."
    ) if start_time.to_date < Date.today 
  end

  def start_time_cannot_change
    errors.add(
      :start_time,
      "-- Can't change the Meeing Date if the Event is still postponed."
    ) if start_time_changed? && start_time_must_be_in_future
  end

  def postponed_cannot_become_false_unless_a_new_start_time_is_submitted_that_is_not_in_the_past
    errors.add(
      :postponed,
      "-- Can't un postpone a Meeting without setting a new Meeting Date that is either today or in the future. Please submit a new Meeting Date if you are updating the Meeting as no longer postponed."
      ) if postponed_changed? && !postponed? && !start_time_changed?
  end


... probably just going to do it in the controller, unless i hear back otherwise, because if @meeting.update many further actions result if these fields did change under these conditions, beyond my current ability to do it in the model if that's even applicable

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

You should probally create N number of methods instead of this soup of conditionals.

Right, thank you. Is there a way to indicate if a field has changed?  Like if  start_time was updated (with the right conditions), then do this and that? (the equivalent of @meeting.start_time_changed?)

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html

You might also want to look into state machine pattern https://blog.appsignal.com/2022/06/22/state-machines-in-ruby-an-introduction.html

Ok, I appreciate that ty. All the stuff I need to do as a result of the conditions would have to come after the instance is updated, which seems controller, so I'll have to look at it more. btw, i am using an old version of Ruby - I'm writing tests for an old site (hobbyist) before I try updating it, but might 3rd party the updates due to lack of time and skills

Putting complex logic into the controller is rarely a good idea as controllers are notoriously hard to test. Not everything in Rails has to go into M, V or C.

Instead of lumping all the buisness logic of your model into a single crazy tree of of conditional branches use individual validations for each aspect. I think you're actually overcomplicating it.
You can control when validations are fired with the on: option and writing custom validators is as easy as creating a method and using validate :method_name. If you want to create more complex validators create a validator class.
class Meeting
  validates :start_time, presence: true
  validate :start_time_must_be_in_future, 
    if: :start_time?, # prevents a nil error
    unless: :postponed?,
    on: :create       
  validate :start_time_cannot_change,
    if: :postponed?
    on: :update

  private

  def start_time?
    !start_time.nil?
  end

  def start_time_must_be_in_future
    errors.add(
      :start_time,
      "Meeting must be at least one day in the future."
    ) if start_time.to_date <= Date.today 
  end

  def start_time_cannot_change
    errors.add(
      :start_time,
      "Can't change the Meeting Date if the Meeting is still postponed."
    ) if will_save_change_to_start_date?
  end
end

There are gems such as validates_timeliness that make temporal validations less onerous.

As of Rails 7 we can use validate :start_time, comparison: {greater_than: ->{Date.today} } and then obviously add the if, unless, on, and message options.

start_time? should work by default and its datatype shouldn't be a string as in OP question

Thank you. So how do I tell the controller these specific attributes have changed? For the 100 lines of code that results if start_time or postponed being updated (emails etc). Or do I pop all that in the model. But also I'd like to send extra alert to view ('You changed this, so now this has happened successfully as anticipated.'), so need to send something to controller eventually. ... Generally, my previous opinion of models was mostly associations and superficial form restrictions.

Ah, validations fire when saving (updating, persisting), so I can still determine what changed from within the controller as per OP question. ... surprising that logic did not fall into place until now. "Before saving an Active Record object, Rails runs your validations...."  Also, Rails is an MVC framework

will_save_change_to_start_date? should be how to determine if a new :start_time is being saved, and then I need a similar one for :postponed - can't render it false if previously true, unless start_time is also updated and in the future

Nm got it ty, updated my question with current
